# Getting publish_actions permission with just a common Post action

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

My Facebook app's permission dialog doesn't ask for publish_actions permission even though I said it should.  I think the reason has to do with not having any Open Graph actions declared.  However, I want to use a common Post action, and common actions don't get declared -- in fact, if you try to create a Post action in Open Graph manually, you get the error: A custom Post action is restricted. Please use the common Post action instead.

What's the solution in order to get the publish_actions permission, if you are only going to use common actions that Facebook predefines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure you are actually requesting the permissions in your permission scope array. For example, this doesn't set your permissions

[image: Permission configure]

The above is only for the App Center. Usage must be as the following in PHP SDK

```php
$params = array(
  'scope' => 'publish_actions',
  'redirect_uri' => 'https://www.myapp.com/post_login_page'
);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

or in the JS SDK

```js
 FB.login(function(response) {
   // handle the response
 }, {scope: 'publish_actions'});
```

For more information see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#adding